# How do you convert a changing input (square wave) into a single high signal?

Tags: frequency, pulse, waveform, square

I am designing a circuit which will output a square waveform for a specific duration of time (t) but I need to be able to read the square waveform using a processor so would like to turn the changing square waveform into a single high pulse for time (t). The frequency of the waveform could be too high for the processor to read directly so I am looking for a method to convert it to a single high pulse (with duration t). I first thought about using a small capacitor which would be charged up during the rise of the square waveform and then be discharged through the low part of the waveform but I am unsure if this would work and what value the capacitor would need to be. Ideally I need way which does not use ICs (simple discrete components only would be best).
Any ideas?
Dan

Comment: Have you tried a LPF?

Comment: An LPF, followed by a comparator if you need a logic level output, should work fine.

Comment: Would a comparator work though during the low parts of the square waveform (my output is basically a chain of square pulses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a retriggerable one-shot, like the [74HC423](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT423.pdf)  The first rising edge will make the output high, and each subsequent rising edge will keep it high.  The output will not go low until there is a time period between rising edges that exceed the output pulse width.

In the world of logic chips, one-shots aren't the greatest of ideas, and are considered to be cheats in many cases, but here it seems to make OK sense.

Answer (score 0):

What is required is an RC & a circuit with a schmitt input.
This couple be constructed from a comparator or...a couple of 74HC14 - schmitt input inverter (two just to re-invert the original inversion)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJTnvH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6WxKD.png)</sup>

Comment: That would delay the rising edge of the output to be later than the beginning of the square wave, while a retriggerable one shot won't.  This might be fine behavior for the asker.

Comment: True, he might not want that. but it is easily fixed - diode. Its just another way of doing something similar

Comment: The cap will charge (almost instantly) but will take longer to discharge on a low. As long as a 74HC14 is used it will be fine